# Implementing my own tuple class - what should I consider?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, class-design, stdtuple

I plan on writing an implementation of `std::tuple`. Or to be more exact, I need to write a class which :

- implements a tuple.
- has its own equivalent of `std::get()` (also as a freestanding function).
- behaves very much like `std::tuple` in typical use, but
- is not necessarily a perfect replacement of `std::tuple`, i.e. it may have behavior differences in corner cases. Specifically, if there the standards committee has had any regrettable choices with `std::tuple`, I don't necessarily want to repeat them.
- May depend on a bit of the standard library, but preferably not on any run-time functions. So, `<type_traits>` or `<cstdint>` dependencies are fine, some of `<utility>` like `std::forward()`, but let's not go crazy.
- Should be written in C++11, although C++14 may be relevant if it makes it a whole lot easier/better somehow.

My question has several parts:

- Is it reasonable, given my constraints, to adapt the libstdc++ or libc++ implementation? Perhaps cutting out or replacing some unnecessary/unfortunate parts?
- What significant design decisions will I need to make, when either adapting or writing this anew?

Note: Obviously, this is for an environment where the standard library itself is not available.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are there really platforms where you have C++14 but no standard library? Or is this for some sort of interview/assignment, etc.

Comment: @jfh: Yes there are, but - I'm not sure whether to spell it out, because then the answers might focus on that platform rather than my question.

Comment: Maybe you want to take a look at EASTL's implementation ( https://github.com/electronicarts/EASTL/blob/master/include/EASTL/tuple.h ). I don't know whether it's 100% standard-compliant, and it does use some C++17, but the whole project does have some of the same goals as you do.

Comment: Could be embedded.  You have a lot of passive-aggressive BS from some of them, such as "SEGGER Embedded Studio for ARM provides a limited C++ library suitable for use in an embedded application" - And they don't even have `<algorithm>` it's all just wrappers for the C library - https://studio.segger.com/index.htm?https://studio.segger.com/libcpp_reference.htm

Comment: The GCC 4.8.2 implementation is pretty straight forward and 1101 lines, and is actually a surprisingly easy read given the often esoteric format gcc insists on using so may be a good reference. As far as what I would suggest, forward everything! I'd  implement std::tie, the std::pair specializations are really not that important unless you'll use them. You may want to specialize a tuple to have multiple members as opposed to just one (possibly influenced by implementation and word boundaries, indicated via tag at make_tuple, etc.), I personally can't stand expanding more than 5 in my debugger.

Comment: @jfh: Are you familiar enough with it to describe the differences between it, the libc++ implementation, and EASTL's?

Comment: @einpoklum I just poured through it quickly, it appears theat they pretty much do the same thing, with only minor differences like EASTL providing an (unnecessary?) specialization for when the current element is a reference type. They appear to use nearly the same exact API regardless. Also the reason for asking about your platform boils down to whether you can do things like structured bindings if you don't have the std::get to specialize, as reopening the std namespace is techincally undefined behavior except for specialization of user-defined type.